# SpreadsheetNotFound Error for Python when trying to write to Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts, gspread

OS: Windows 11
Python 3.11, using VS Code

So, I want to use a python script to autofill a bunch of cells in a google spreadsheet, and I was using the guide at https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/read-write-google-sheets-python/. My code to access the spreadsheet and make sure I can write is as follows:

```
# for writing to google sheets, from https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/read-write-google-sheets-python/

import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json

scopes = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("[filename].json", scopes) 
file = gspread.authorize(credentials) 
sheet = file.open("[spreadsheetName]") 
sheet = sheet.testSheet
```

So, I run the code, and get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[pythonScriptPath]", line 15, in 
sheet = file.open("[spreadsheetName]")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "[anotherPath]", line 160, in open
raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

Now, I've googled this error and one possible cause was that I didn't share the spreadsheet with the email in the json file. However, I shared it with the email beforehand (ends in iam.gserviceaccount.com) and set it as editor, and even after double-checking and running the script again I'm still getting the error. Could anyone tell me what I'm missing here, please? And the json file and the script are in the same folder.

EDIT: Solved, by instead changing up how I did things and instead using something I found from the gspread documentation (WORKSHEET_NAME is a constant I defined elsewhere in the code, the caps-in-brackets are just the relevant string that I've removed for anonymization):

```
credentials = gspread.service_account(filename=r'[JSON_FILE_PATH]')
spreadsheet = credentials.open_by_url('[GOOGLE_SHEET_URL]') 
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(WORKSHEET_NAME)
```

Comment: _the json file and the script are in the same folder_ Why would this matter?  The problem is with opening the **spreadsheet** file, not the **json** file, yes?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it did matter or not, so I figured I'd mention it in case it did

Comment: Is your spread sheet in your google drive called `[spreadsheetName]` with the brackets? Also, is your credentials file actually called `[filename].json`?

Comment: No, and it wasn't called that in the script either; I had just used the brackets to anonymize things

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your service account dosent have access to the file.

The fastest way to fix it is to open the service account json file and find the service account email address its the only one with a @ in it

now go to google drive and share the file with the service account like you would any other user

option number two requires that you have a goggle workspace domain and can configure domain wide deligation

Comment: But as I mentioned in the post, I already shared the spreadsheet with the service account email. Do I need to do anything past that?

Comment: I can't help much with gspread I just use the API directly the error implys to me it doesn't have access